# How to use data.table to select all dataframe rows that meet a condition and if the condition is not met in a group, select the first row of group?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use data.table for this because the actual dataset this is intended for is huge. I'd like to use data.table to select all dataframe rows that meet a condition (in this example, "monthX" column value > 0), and if the condition is not met for the group (group in this case defined as same "ID"), then select the first row of that group. So, each ID would end up with one row regardless of the value in "monthX". Any recommendations for how to do this? The below illustrates this better, and code for deriving that dataframe is provided at the bottom of this post:

[image]

Code:

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(
  ID=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,4)),
  Mo = c(seq(1:3),seq(1:3),seq(1:4)),
  stX= c("NA","X","X","NA","NA","NA","NA","X","NA","NA")
  )
df2 <- df1
df2 <- setDT(df2)[, firstX := +(.I == .I[stX == 'X'][1]),ID][
        , monthX := ifelse(firstX == 1,Mo,0)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may get the first row index (`.I`) based on the condition grouped by 'ID' and `fcoalesce` with the first row index, extract the column 'V1' and subset

```
library(data.table)
df2[df2[, fcoalesce(.I[monthX > 0][1], .I[1]), ID]$V1]
```

-output

```
   ID Mo stX firstX monthX
1:  1  2   X      1      2
2:  2  1  NA     NA     NA
3:  3  2   X      1      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an `if` `else` conditional. Also picking the first matching row if more than one values meet the condition `> 0`

```
df2[, if(any(monthX > 0 & !is.na(monthX))){.SD[monthX > 0][1]} 
        else{.SD[1]}, by=ID]
   ID Mo stX firstX monthX
1:  1  2   X      1      2
2:  2  1  NA     NA     NA
3:  3  2   X      1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the purpose of your helper columns "firstX" and "monthX", perhaps you are just looking after this?

```
setorder(df2, ID, stX, Mo, na.last = T)[, .SD[1], ID]
```